# Unauthorized access when I try to open the generated executable of a Windev project

Tags: windows, security, authorization, exe, windev

I downloaded an executable generated from a Windev project, I put all the files associated with this executable in the correct locations. However, when I run the .exe file an 'unauthorized access' window still pops up.
Do you have an idea on the cause of such a problem or a solution for this case?

Thank you.

Comment: [What Causes the "File Downloaded from the Internet" Warning and How Can I Easily Remove It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/70012/what-causes-the-file-downloaded-from-the-internet-warning-and-how-can-i-easily-remove-it/)

Answer (score 1):

That normal if the app you downloaded need some administrator privileges to do some stuff , if you're the developer of the app you can turn off the alerts in the process of creating the exe, otherwise there's 'almost nothing' you can do to stop them